# How to run Dart tests in IntelliJ with NNBD experiment enabled?

Tags: dart, intellij-idea

I am on *Dart 2.10.0-92.0.dev* and I am trying to port my libraries to use null-saftey / non-nullable / NNBD.

I've enabled the experiment in `analysis_options.yaml` and the analyzer in IntelliJ is correctly displaying errors and warning.

I can successfully run tests from the command line, and in IntelliJ using a *Dart Command Line App* by passing `--enable-experiment=non-nullable` as a VM option.

It is unclear to me how I can run a *Dart Test* in IntelliJ? I keep on getting the following error, and I can't figure out how to pass the experiment flag?

```
Error: This requires the null safety language feature, which is experimental.
You can enable the experiment using the '--enable-experiment=non-nullable' command line option.
```

Comment: please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25687 to be notified on any progress with it

Comment: Thank you, I've upvoted the bug report and linked this question in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today's Dart plugin update adds 'VM Options' field to the Dart Test run configuration. Click Help -> Check for Updates... in the IDE to get it.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do it's to put `--enable-experiment=non-nullable` in the VM options while Editing the configuration:
[image]

Comment: As I write, this works for _Dart Command Line App_ run/debug configurations, but I don't have such an option for _Dart Test_.

Answer (score 1):

To run Dart tests configuration with NNBD enabled, you need to add the VMOptions in the "run configuration" file :

1. Check the  **"Store as project file"** options in the  "Edit configuration" window,
2. Open the generated configuration file ( YOUR_PROJECT/.idea/runConfigurations/YOUR_RUN_TEST.xml ) and add this line before the filePath option :

```xml
<option name="VMOptions" value="--enable-experiment=non-nullable --no-sound-null-safety" />
```

Your file should look like :

```xml
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="false" name="my tests" type="DartTestRunConfigurationType" factoryName="Dart Test" nameIsGenerated="true">
    <option name="VMOptions" value="--enable-experiment=non-nullable --no-sound-null-safety" />
    <option name="filePath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/srv/ytbx021-run-api/app" />
    <option name="scope" value="FOLDER" />
    <method v="2" />
  </configuration>
</component>
```

3. Then run your tests, **it will fail one more time**, but on the next run it should run in null safety mode.